# Android Media Player stops after playing twice

Tags: android, loops, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play the default ringtone 5 times. The relevant code is as follows :-

```
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);        
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
      int maxCount = 5;

      @Override
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
        if(count < maxCount) {  // count initialised to 1 previously
          count++;
          player.seekTo(0);
          player.start();
        }
    }});
    player.start();
```

But it only plays twice. However, when I run it through the debugger using eclipse, it correctly plays 5 times.
Any ideas would be very much appreciated.
Thanks very much in advance
p

Comment: Update: it works if I put a thread sleep of a couple of seconds prior to the player.start() in the onCompletion() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI` keeps playing like an endless stream, thus `OnCompletion` is never fired. But, you can `player.getDuration()`. Using `Timer` works.

```
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
    player.start();
    int maxCount = 5;

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            player.stop();
        }
    }, player.getDuration() * maxCount);
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. However, when I run through the debugger, the onCompletion() is executed each time, and as mentioned, I get the 5 rings.